# can't catch a tone frequency of 15k with microphone c# naudio

Tags: c#, fft, naudio, frequency-analysis

I record some sound with NAudio to float array and after getting the  recorded audio I want to convert it back from float array to wav to check it.

I wrote a method but I'm not sure about it because: I try to record a 15Khz tone of 5 seconds and pass it through fft to check for the spectrum to ensure the 15k was catched. 
These are my steps:

1. I generate this tone with matlab firstly and record with Audacity that it is the right tone. Audacity shows a nice spectrum with a peak in 15k with -30db.
2. I try to record with Naudio the tone and then converting it back from the recorded float array to wav to check it in Audacity. unfortunately, it show nothing but some noise up to 12k and no more(-80db at 12k).

Here is the regular recording convertion when data is available:

```
void myWaveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        myMemoryStream.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);//this is for playing the myMemoryStream
        for (int index = 0; index < e.BytesRecorded; index += 2)//Here I convert in a loop the stream into floating number samples
        {

            short sample = (short)((e.Buffer[index + 1] << 8) |
                                    e.Buffer[index + 0]);
            samples32.Add(sample / 32768f);//IEEE 32 floating number 
        }
    }
```

This is my code for converting back:

```
void floatBackToStream(float[] myfloatArray)
    {
        short[] myShort = new short [myfloatArray.Length];
        myMemoryStream2 = new MemoryStream();
        for (int i = 0; i < myfloatArray.Length; i++)
        {
            myShort[i] = (short)(myfloatArray[i] * 32768f);
            myMemoryStream2.WriteByte((byte)(myShort[i] & 255));
            myMemoryStream2.WriteByte((byte)(myShort[i] >> 8));
        }

        myMemoryStream2.Position = 0;
        myRaw2 = new RawSourceWaveStream(myMemoryStream2, new WaveFormat(44100,1));
        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile("C:/Users/alon/Desktop/myRecordings/myCalibration.wav", myRaw2);

    }
```

Comment: Sounds like there is a low pass filter in there somewhere... What sampling rate are you using? Can you use standard recording software to record your tone?

Comment: 44.1Khz. No digital filter applied. I must record with the NAudio class.

Comment: How did you setup your `WaveInEvent`? By default, it uses a 8kHz sampling rate.

Comment: myWaveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);

Comment: When I said there is probably a low pass filter I was referring to the sound card. If you can't record 15kHz it's possible that it's either your sound card has a low pass filter, or your microphone does not respond to 15kHz.

Comment: When debugging you want to first isolate the system that is failing. I am suggesting you swap out one of the systems to see if the issue is how you are using NAudio.

Comment: Hello, I think something is wrong with NAudio. When I record with Audacity I see a perfect spectrum. In NAudio after recording the same thing I write it to binary file in order to convert it into an array to see the spectrum in matlab. It shows a very bad spectum in matlab.Also when I play it from Audacity and the recorded from NAudio I feel that NAudio is distorting the stream. I can provide some links for pictures of the spectrums if needed

Comment: You can try to design a band-pass filter that will increase frequency from 12 kHz till 15 kHz. Maybe then we could retrieve this part of signal. I can create filter like that and write a differential equation for you, just tell me, if you want it.

Comment: @RafałPieńkowski
It can be great if can do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so: I created a band-pass filter, with peaks at 15 kHz. Peak value is +80dB since you said that you have -80dB at 12 kHz. If we want filter to work well, it needs to be a high order transfer function. So the equations could get quite long, but it is just multiplication and addition, therefore it won't take a long time for the CPU to perform. I assumed your sampling rate to be 44,1 kHz. The equation is as follows:

```
y[k]=a7*u[k-1]+a6*u[k-2]+a5*u[k-3]+a4*u[k-4]+a3*u[k-5]+a2*u[k-6]+a1*u[k-7]+a0*u[k-8] -b7*y[k-1]-b6*y[k-2]-b5*y[k-3]-b4*y[k-4]-b3*y[k-5]-b2*y[k-6]-b1*y[k-7]-b0*y[k-8];
```

Where `u` is the measured signal and `y` is a new vector that will contain the 15 kHz frequency. Now there are 2 approaches to estimate coefficients:

1. pulse [rad/s] = 2*pi * frequency [Hz]

This is the proper physical equation. Coeffecients:

```
a7=207.5; 
a6=-578.1;
a5=546.6;
a4=-149.8;
a3=-49.39;
a2=22.21;
a1=1.349;
a0=0.006915;
b7=-0.945;
b6=0.3907;
b5=-0.09229;
b4=0.01363;
b3=-0.001288;
b2=0.00007605;
b1=-2.567*10^(-6);
b0=3.79*10^(-8);
```

2. The second way is to assume that pulses are in [Hz]. Don't blame me, even some IDE programs follow this inappropriate approach.

For this case we have following coefficients:

```
a7=3.301;
a6=8.643;
a5=-51.47;
a4=59.35;
a3=-5.498;
a2=-23.56;
a1=8.625;
a0=0.6114;
b7=-5.693;
b6=14.18;
b5=-20.19;
b4=17.96;
b3=-10.22;
b2=3.638;
b1=-0.7397;
b0=0.0658;
```

Just try both of them and see what you get. Make sure to use a datatype of sufficient precision, to make sure we wont multiply times 0.

Comment: Hello Rafal, did you extract the coefficients by matlab? How can I calculate coefficients for other frequency?

Comment: Well, for designing filters you must have good knowledge of Bode plot. Assume you want to cut off frequency above 10 kHz. This is pulse 2*pi*10000 rad/s. Next you calculate time constant T = 1/pulse. Simply filter is first-order dynamics system, and its transfer function is G = k / (1+sT), where k is gain and should be 1.

Comment: So you create this transfer function in Matlab, using command tf(..). Next you have to change you'r  continous function to discrete function, using c2d(...). The transfer function is equals to Y/U, so you get an equation Y x function_denominator = U  x function_nominator. The operator in discrete function is "z", and multiply times z means one sample ahead, so for example Y*(2 + 5z) = 2y[k] + 5y[k+1]. Change the equation to the form like y[k+1] = f(y[k], y[k-1], ..., u[k], u[k-1], ...). Then you have equation ready to implement in any programming language.